# Why is Visual Studio building an unrelated project?

Tags: visual-studio

I have a large number of projects in my solution, but the main two that are of interest are projects A and B.  Project A has no reference to project B.  Here's what happens in a few scenarios:

1. Build project A.  Project A builds as expected.
2. Run project A without debugging.  Project A builds as expected.
3. Debug project A.  Project A builds as expected, but build output gets wiped when complete and VS starts building project B.
4. Unload project B and debug project A.  Project A builds as expected.

Based on these, I think I can safely say that there are no dependencies on project B from project A.  I've also searched all the .csproj files, as well as the .sln file itself.  There are no references to project B anywhere that I don't expect any (obvious by the namespace prefixes).  What could be causing scenario 3 to rebuild project B?

Comment: By default, Visual Studio will build all projects in a solution. You can mark projects as "don't build" by opening the Solution Configuration Manager window.

Comment: @Dai It should only build a project if there were changes to its source code, or changes to something that it depends on.